# How to make user authentication via social services

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I want to try to make user authentication via social services in my node js/express application. But I don't how. Can you advise a good modules out there?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

- [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)
- [passport](http://passportjs.org/)

Comment: @Erik Two implementations for the same thing. These things happen with open source.

Answer (score 0):

This is a boilerplate app for social login that I put together:

https://github.com/nikolaydyankov/node-social-auth

It provides simple authentication with Facebook, Twitter and Google. It uses Express, Passport and MongoDB for storing sessions.